# IE hangs up during execution of Tests through cc.net

Tags: internet-explorer, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am experiencing IE hangup since long. When I execute my tests through nunit directly, it works fine. but when I try to execute them through cc.net they seems to hangup at some point and without any reason. It stops the execution of all tests at that point. And even dont run the teardown fixture in which I am closing IE.

Can anyone plz help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging on to the CC.NET box as the user under which the service is configured to run and firing up IE? You'll probably find that there is a dialog to specify initial options like Internet connection that the user in question hasn't yet OKed on that machine.

**Detailed instructions:**

Make a remote desktop connection to the server, or log on to it physically if you have access, using the logon details under which the CC.NET service is configured to run. If it is configured to run as the local system account, you will need to configure it to run as a user account instead to get this working.

Once on the machine, fire up Internet Explorer, and my guess is that you will be presented with the dialog for setting up your Internet connection. Go through the wizard and OK everything. Then log off again. Now, when you try to run your CC.NET build, you should find it works.

**Alternative:**

You should be able to disble this wizard for the local system account. Check the following registry value:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Internet Connection Wizard\Completed
```

This should have the REG_BINARY value 01 00 00 00. S-1-5-18 is the fixed SID for the Local System account.

Comment: Will I still be able to interact with desktop after using this logon. As prevuisly I am using Local system account and also option of interacting with desktop os checked. As my applciation is interactive.

Comment: It should just be a question of setting permissions and granting rights in the local security policy. I'm assuming you have sufficient rights on the CC.NET server to be able to grant these things...

Comment: Have added an alternative way around this that may be simpler given what you've added in your comment.

Comment: Yes. I have rights to make changes. I just want to know Will the test be able to interact with desktop or not. or by default it allows

Comment: Yes, It has the Reg_Binary 01000000. But there is also a ShellNext with Reg_SZ set to http://testsite. Any idea what that means

Comment: I believe the option to interact with desktop is automatic in the case of a specific user account - could be wrong, but you could always try it and see. Can always change back again. As for ShellNext, not sure. Perhaps worth Googling?